# IIOP1002: Principal propagation: Cannot find principal information in subject - Apache Shiro + EJB

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, ejb, shiro

I am using Shiro Security to secure a JSF project.

It is working as expected, including calls to a remote EJB (that is unsecured). However, when a call to the unsecure EJB is made, i have the following warn, but the method is executed without a problem:

```
IIOP1002: Principal propagation: Cannot find principal information in subject
```

What does this exactly mean? What should I do to fix this? I need to execute the method in a remote EJB from a secured application and this warning is getting dumped to the log everytime a call to the EJB is made (this occurs multiple times).

**Edit:**

The warn doesn't occur when I deploy the project in the same Glassfish server as the EJB.

**Edit 2:**

I thought about inserting the principal information in the InitialContext, before doing the call to the EJB, like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal());
ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

Still no luck.

SecurityUtils is from `org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils` library.

Comment: I'm guessing it is a Glassfish config issue. How are your instances configured?

Comment: I don't know if it's a Glassfish configuration issue, because all the instances have the same configuration. It happens when I try to access the EJB from another glassfish instance. For example: I'm running a local application with Shiro Security and then try to access the remote EJB (in another glassfish instance), it gives me the error. However, if I run in the same instance, i don't get the error/warn.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Shiro is an application layer security solution. As far as I can tell it is not integrated with your application server in any way.

A Java EE server normally expects to be in charge of authentication, authorisation, etc. Consequently it is then in a position to be able to propagate credentials correctly when making both local and remote EJB calls. This is how features like [javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) are implemented.

Comment: But why when I don't use Shiro I don't get this warning? I was using this application without a problem before implementing Shiro (but it didn't have security at all).

Comment: Perhaps Shiro has hacked* in it's own version of [java.security.Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html), which has subsequently surprised GlassFish?  *I mean this in a nice way!

Comment: Maybe... but I have no idea how to check this. I'm reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Shiro propagates its principal to javax.security.Principal, which remote EJBs don't understand. The Java principal has to be nulled out.
This is done in [Shiro EE integration module](https://github.com/flowlogix/flowlogix/tree/5.x/jakarta-ee/shiro-ee) which will be integrated into Shiro with version 2.0+

Comment: The link to https://github.com/flowlogix/flowlogix/tree/main/jakarta-ee/shiro-ee is broken at the moment. Do you maybe have a new link?

Comment: Jakarta EE module has now been integrated into Shiro itself. See https://shiro.apache.org/jakarta-ee.html

Comment: I have fixed the link to point to the older 5.x version of flowlogix library so it still works as well